# How can we Make separate option for standing Orders

Tags: civievent, civicontribute

Is there any way to make a separate option for the orders which are not delivered yet or standing orders in civi.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can add a new payment method - Standing Order

Steps:
Administers -> System Settings -> Option Groups

Look for "Payment Methods" - Edit the option and add a new payment method and call it as **"Standing Order"**

I guess this helps!!!